# formatting html page output using css and php

Tags: php, html, css

I write out a list of available players to my html page--however my list is almost 65 players long.
I split the html page out using the following css

```
#right_side {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 675px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  font-family: italic;
}
```

the PHP code loops through the list in the following way:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<li>".$row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName']."</li>";
    echo"<br>";
    }
```

How do I break up the results so they are into 3 columns of 20 instead of one column of 60?

Comment: You will need to set up a counter when you loop thorough your results.

I'd change your while loop to a for loop. When the counter hits 20, close off the `<ul>` then start again.

Comment: Use a pagination method and set the `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css

```
li 
{
      display:inline-block;
      width:30%;
}
```

This will give you

1   |     2    |  3

4   |     5    |  6

etc

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cmw7T/

Comment: i think your solution is more correct than me sir. apologise me

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin that would depend. You could style the  3 `ul` to display across the page. This would be more suitable if the OP requires a diferent orientation to the data. My CSS should guide you in the right direction. Both solutions have merit.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

php

```
 $total_num_each_column = mysql_num_rows($result) / 3;
    $count = 0;
        echo "<ul id='box'>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if($count > $total_num_each_column) {
        echo "</ul> <ul id='box'>";
        }
        echo "<li>".$row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName']."</li>";
        if($count > $total_num_each_column) {
        echo "</ul>";
        } 
        $count++;
        }
```

css

```
#box {
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: `ul` is a block element be default. As it stands this wont give the columns but three lists, one on top of the other.

Comment: Close but not quite... IDs need to be unique. Change ID to class and that should do it.

Comment: Missing semi-colon in `$count = 0` - Plus, this `echo "</ul> <ul id="box">";` and this `echo "<ul id="box">";` will throw a parse error.

Comment: i change to echo "<ul id='box'>";

Comment: You also have a missing semi-colon in `echo "</ul>"`